# PHP in_array( 0, ['aaa', 'bbb'] ) returns TRUE?

Tags: php, arrays

Can somebody explain me please why this command returns TRUE?

```
var_dump( in_array( 0, ['aaa', 'bbb'] ), TRUE );
```

Comment: Looks more like a simple typo to me...

Comment: To be fair, you're var_dumping `true` literally, so that's one reason too =P

Answer (score 5):

move a close bracket

```
var_dump( in_array( 0, ['aaa', 'bbb'] , TRUE));
```

Now you ask:

```
var_dump(
    in_array( 0, ['aaa', 'bbb']), 
    TRUE
);
```

both of them return true

Comment: Yes thats it. Thanks.

Comment: You are welcome!